# getting TimeoutException when using expected_conditions in heroku

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, webdriverwait, screen-size

I have a selenium robot that worked perfectly locally but on heroku TimeoutException raises whenever its on a expected_condition (element_to_be_clickable, visibility_of_element_located and presence_of_element_located). Anyone knows how to fix this problem in heroku.
here is an example where I used expected_conditions

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'productlistning__btn')]")))
```

and the chrome arguments that I used in my code:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Are you working in headless mode?

Comment: yes. it's required to deploy on heroku

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't define the screen size for the driver while in headless mode the default screen size is 800,600.
So, to make your Selenium code working try setting the screen size to maximal or 1920,1080. As following:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
```

Or

```py
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
```

Comment: i do have those arguments in my code. here are the arguments I have.```chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), options=chrome_options)```

Comment: Please add this to the question to make it readable

Comment: Are you sure `--` should be before `start-maximized`? I'm using it as you can see in my code and it works.

Comment: hmmm, could be the case, but it worked just fine with `--` locally

Comment: have you tried that?

Comment: yea, it's the same

Comment: If so I'm sorry, I have no idea what is the problem there. I never used heroku